# Install rpm from custom repo

Tags: linux, package-management, yum, repository

I created a custom repo on one of my machines that I am able to grab updates from. However I also want to be able to install packages such as emacs,gcc, and the such from the repo. The updates work correctly and install. However if I do `yum install emacs` or `yum install gcc` using my custom repo, it says there is nothing to install. How do I go about adding package install to my repo? I know I can do `wget` to do this but prefer to have yum manage the install.

The repo file looks like such

```
[repo] 
gpgcheck=0 
enabled=1 
name=customrepo 
baseurl=http://path_to_my_repo

# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
customrepo                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00     
customrepo/primary_db                                    | 436 kB     00:00     
repo                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
repo/primary_db                                          | 436 kB     00:00     
repo id                          repo name                                status
customrepo                       Custom Repository                        158
repo                             Updates                                  158
repolist: 316
```

Comment: Have you [added your custom repo](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html).  If you haven't the system can't "see" the new packages

Comment: @eyoung100 yes i have and it sees my repo for updates but not new packages.

Comment: Could you post the output of the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` you used? The output of `sudo yum repolist`.

Comment: `[repo]
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
name=custom repo
baseurl=http://path_to_my_repo` and I'm not at the computer with the vm right now to do the repolist but will do that when I get back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `sudo yum clean all` then run `sudo yum update` and the system should now have all updates and software new to the server.